# Spring Batch application not detecting the beans even if annotations are put

Tags: annotations, spring-batch

I believe I have correctly used the annotations @EnableBatchProcessing and @Autowire but I cannot resolve that error. The package structure is correct.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36xGL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so4b4.png)

I was expecting to resolve the issue but I did not

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you share, it seems like you are using Spring Batch v5.0.0. In this version, `JobBuilderFactory` and `StepBuilderFactory` are not registered as beans in the application context by `@EnableBatchProcessing` anymore. This is mentioned in the Javadoc of [@EnableBatchProcessing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html). There are no `JobBuilder` or `StepBuilder` beans registered neither, so you cannot autowire such beans in your configuration class like you shared in your code.

The way to define your job with v5 is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {
 
   @Bean
   public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
               // define job flow as needed
               .build();
    }
 
}
```

The same pattern can be used for steps as well.